# MVVM Prism EventToCommandBehavior with NavigateTo raise ArgumentNullException(TargetName)

Tags: xaml, mvvm, navigation, prism

In a Xamarin Forms project I'm trying to navigate from a page that contain a list of items to another page when the user select an item.
I want the navigation declared in xaml and the *ItemSelected* of the event args passed as parameters.
When I tap the item an *ArgumentNullException* is raised:

*Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: TargetElement*

this is the code

```
<ListView.Behaviors>
    <b:EventToCommandBehavior 
        EventName="ItemSelected"
        Command="{prism:NavigateTo 'ContractVersionV'}"
        EventArgsParameterPath="SelectedItem"
        />
</ListView.Behaviors>
```

If I don't use the *NavigateTo* extension and manage the navigation with command in viewModel all work.

Is possible what i'm trying to do?

#### UPDATE

The stack trace is:

in Prism.Xaml.ParentPageAwareExtension`1.Initialize()
   in Prism.Navigation.Xaml.NavigationExtensionBase.d__16.MoveNext()
   in System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c.b__7_0(Object state)
   in System.Threading.WinRTSynchronizationContextBase.Invoker.InvokeCore()

[Here](https://github.com/DellaMoraWalter/PrismToNavigateTest) a simple project that reproduce the problem.

Start and click on an item.

Comment: Where's the stacktrace?

Comment: Updated with stack trace and link to a simple project that reproduce the error

Answer (score 0):

That's because IProvideValueTarget.TargetObject is null which may be because behaviors are - let's say - outside of the visual tree.
However I think it's a bug though. Maybe Brian Lagunas has a solution for this case.

I came up with an attached command on ListView which executes on ItemTapped.

So instead:

```
<ListView.Behaviors>
    <b:EventToCommandBehavior 
        EventName="ItemTapped"
        Command="{prism:NavigateTo 'MyPage'}"
        EventArgsParameterPath="Item" />
</ListView.Behaviors>
```

You can:

```
<ListView ListViewExtensions.ItemTappedCommand="{prism:NavigateTo 'MyPage'}" />
```

I made it work this way but I'm not quite happy about it. 
And bringing in a ItemTemplate using a Button with the command seems easy and simple but not the right choice, especially when you already have a more complex item template.